# Does the construct do .. while(false) contribute to better control flow?

Tags: language-agnostic, control-flow

I've recently come across this code:

```
do {
    if ( ! checkSomething() )
        break;

    // some code

    if ( ! checkSomeOtherThing() )
        break;

    // some other code
} while(false);

// some final code
```

The programmer that wrote it, wrote a comment along the lines of `"cleaner control flow"`.

In my opinion, the original code could look better if its refactored into something else. But is there any truth in this statement ? Is this construct any good ?

Comment: Into "something else". Exactly how are we supposed to judge this given you haven't defined "something else"?

Comment: I would say this is no better than putting a `goto` label before "some final code" and goto-ing it; at least with goto the label is explicit. This code is just kinda weird.

Comment: @sje397 this may look like a loop, but it's not.  See the loop condition.

Comment: Actually if you think about it, do ... while (false) means that you don't need the loop at all!

Comment: @vic but `break` statements do need a loop.

Comment: @Noon Silk You are right, I haven't defined "something else", but its not really where I wanted to go with this question (i.e. not towards refactoring options, but with the possible problems with the loop itself, which was the discussion I came across when we found it). In my case, I would have extracted the loop contents to a new function, and change `breaks` to `returns`.

Comment: @robert I meant exactly what you have posted in your answer =)

Comment: This appears to have its roots in a C macro trick that allows you to define a macro such that multiple function calls can be inlined at the macro call point in a semantically correct way. See http://www.noveltheory.com/TechPapers/while.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind loops containing several `break` statements, then the only problem here is that C (for obvious reasons) doesn't let you break out of a bare block, hence the "non-loop" which some unsuspecting future maintainer could mistake for a real loop.

The considerations, I think, are:

- if there are only two `break` points, what's so bad about two `if` statements?
- if there are more than two break points then the indentation with `if` statements could get unpleasant, and this saves that, but then again is the function doing too much? And even if not, would it be better just to use `goto` and avoid the weirdness of a loop that doesn't loop?

Since you tag this language-agnostic, I used to use a macroised assembly language, with a `block` ... `endblock` that you could break out of. This lead to reasonably nice code for checking necessary conditions, such as:

```
block
    breakif str1 == null
    breakif str2 == null
    get some combined property of str1 and str2
    breakif some other condition that stops us getting on with it
    get on with it
endblock
```

Actually, it wasn't `breakif str1 == null`, it was `breakifeq.p str1, null`, or something like that, but I forget exactly what.

Answer (score 6):

I find this much easier to read, and it produces an identical result:

```
if ( checkSomething() )
{
    // some code
    if ( checkSomeOtherThing() )
    {
        // some other code
    }
}
// some final code
```

I think `do ... while` is normally hard to follow, but using it for something other than a loop is misleading at best.

Comment: And I find this far harder. I prefer to leave the control as early as possible. This is quite subjective.

Comment: While I think this code may seem harmless, if there are more breaks in the original piece it will make it far worse. But I do agree that the do ... while(false) construct is very misleading.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to a `goto`.

In such situations, it is better to use a `goto` than to use an ugly hack.

Changing it to use a `goto` makes it much more readable:

```
if (!checkSomething())
    goto Done;

// some code

if (!checkSomeOtherThing())
    goto Done;

// some other code
Done: //some final code
```

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to a goto. Goto can go to anywhere. This will only always go to the end of the loop. You may as well claim goto is always better then `break` or `continue` which is just madness.

Comment: @Noon, @robert: I realize that `goto` can be used for evil.  However, in this case, a `goto` makes the intent much clearer than a loop.

Comment: A `goto` also goes to one place: A label. An explicitly named and descriptive label. Introducing a not-loop here just to use `break` as a thinly-disguised `goto` muddies the issue and is honestly the *worst* possible choice.

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry, but I am not going to argue with someone about using goto. It's mind-bending that that would be neccessary. I must've slipped into a bizarre time warp.

Comment: @robert: It's much easier to find a label than it is to find the end of this particular loop.  (which may be immediately followed by a different indented block)

Comment: @Anon: I never said the currently-coded approach is ideal. Suggesting to replace it with a goto is, in my humble opinion, a bizarre step of logic that I can't quite comprehend.

Comment: @Noon: I do agree that it should probably be refactored.

Comment: @robert: If it's large enough to need to search for the goto, then it's also so large that anyone finding the top of the loop isn't going to immediately realize that it's not actually a loop. Which is *much* worse, especially considering that any decent IDE can jump you directly to the label/point out exactly how far away it is.

Comment: @Anon thats exactly what happened to me at first: I had no clue of what was going on there (`// some code` was actually a bit large). I understood why he did it when I read the comment that was left there, and then I started looking for the breaks inside.

Comment: @Noon: While a proper refactoring is desirable, replacing the not-loop with `goto` s would still be an improvement, without taking the time that a proper refactoring would require. If your control flow pattern is a straight jump that doesn't fit into any other structured control flow pattern, then you *should* be using a goto, even if only to remind yourself that your code might be starting to smell a little.

Comment: @Anon: I completely disagree, but it's a totally useless point to continue discussion on I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the do-while form adopted as a standard to which coders conformed. The advantage is that it communicates, and implements, that the loop will always be executed at least once. This helps isolate, with consistency, the situations where something different occurs, i.e. where the code in the loop is not executed.

This standard was adopted because the Warnier-Orr technique was being applied.

Comment: I disagree with the communication part: there was a comment thrown there that actually told me what the guy tried to do with the `do ... while(false);`. You can easily communicate better by naming that piece of code by placing it in a function.