# Better way to structure/new keyword

Tags: java, c++

Some time ago I came across the following construct which I have rarely seen since, though I use it relatively frequently.  I use it typically when checking on a whole list of conditions are true and it prevents large levels of indentation.  Essentially it uses a for loop to provide a kind of structured goto.  My question is firstly whether there is better way to structure this, secondly whether people like it and thirdly whether a new keyword in java/c++ etc. such as unit { } which would only cause breaks to exit to the end of the unit would be useful and clearer.

ps I realise that it is on slip away from an infinite loop, but I think my paranoia about that has meant its never happened.

Edit: I have added some setup code for the further conditions to try to illuminate problems with chained if then elses

```
boolean valid = false;

// this loop never loops
for (;;)
{
    if (!condition1)
        break;

    condition2.setup();

    if (!condition2)
        break;

    condition3.setup();

    if (!condition3)
        break;

    valid = true;
    break;
}

if (valid) dosomething();
```

EDIT:

I have just discovered that in fact there is a way to structure this in java without misusing loops etc. and wondered whether this would similarily be frowned on, though I guess I have missed the boat on this one.

The restructured code looks like this.

```
boolean valid = false;

breakout:
{
    if (!condition1)
        break breakout;

    condition2.setup();

    if (!condition2)
        break breakout;

    condition3.setup();

    if (!condition3)
        break breakout;

    valid = true;
}

if (valid) dosomething();
```

Now that removes the misuse of the for loop which caused a lot of the complaints, and is actually a solution I think is quite neat and is what I was looking to find originally.
I am guessing that this structure is probably not well known since no one mentioned it, people object to this as strongly?

Comment: As noted below this is just a really confusing way of writing an AND statement.

Comment: Oh man, a classic one - `// this loop never loops`

Comment: This is code that belongs on http://thedailywtf.com

Comment: If you want `goto`, you can always just, you know, use `goto`.  Despite what people say, it's not unethical.

Comment: Am I the only one, or *all* the answers below completely miss the fact that `condition2.setup()` *happens if* `condition1` is good etc.? As a result, how can you conceivably chain the checks? We are simply assuming that they are independent - and it's dangerous to make this assumption if the programmer is writing this type of code!

Comment: Nim, he edited the code to add the setups after we answered with the chained checks... That said, why not put it the setup at the end of the previous if condition block.

Comment: The setup code was added to the question after a lot of the answers below so apologies to them for not making the question clearer, most of them assume (as per original question) that could could simply check conditions 1-3 in one go, my fault.

Comment: Ah, I see, I guess a cursory glance through edit history should be mandatory before one puts one's foot in mouth... :)

Comment: Apologies Nim, loused up the question.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362145/does-the-construct-do-whilefalse-contribute-to-better-control-flow

Comment: -1 You are misleading everyone with the question. While the question is focused in conditions, the code that you added as a comment in one of the answers does not contain conditions, but rather blocks of code with side effects (logging). I am downvoting for this particular reason... it might be too much to expect people to write perfect questions, but the very least that you can expect is that the person most interested in the answer will not withhold information with saying: "Dont really want to put it in the question"

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, the question was a general question over the structure that I wanted peoples thoughts on and I just grabbed the first bit of code I could find when asked, however havent handled the question well, agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's the most readable way of doing it.  Chained `if`-`else if` looks much better.  But if you want to stick with it and don't want to be so close to an infinite loop, you could do something like this:

```
do
{
    if (...)
        break;
    ...
} while (false);
```

Comment: I agree the loop is better, might even start using it.  Just wondering whether it still offends stylistically.  The problem with chained if then elses is when condition2 needs some work doing before it can be evaluated and you end up indenting and indenting.

Comment: Refactor, my friend.  Setup + evaluation == one boolean method!

Comment: This IMHO is the only correct way to do it **and** retain the semantics of the short snippet!

Comment: I would go as far as to say, that you don't need the `valid` boolean, the `dosomething()` should be the last statement in the `while` loop.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer largely because its a better way of doing the same thing.  I have however learnt from nearly every answer to use this only for my own private code since it seems a pretty unpopular/opaque construct!

Answer (score 16):

The loop is counter-intuitive and would be questioned at code review: "Why do you need a loop if you always break on the first iteration?"

Why not use this?

```
boolean valid = true;

if (!condition1)
    valid = false;

else if (!condition2)
    valid = false;

else if (!condition3)
    valid = false;

if (valid) dosomething();
```

Comment: I'd bleeding shoot any programmer of mine that used that loop construct ;)

Comment: I do accept that a for loop that doesnt loop is counter-intuitive (which is why I was suggesting the unit keyword), but once you are familiar with the construct (and I know this is a matter of taste) I find it easier to understand than your answer.  Plus your answer is really hiding the indentation which might not be possible is a more complicated example.

Comment: OMG seriously, unless I'm completely missing something isn't he just writing if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {doSomething()} in the most confusing way possible?

Comment: @aronp: I fail to see the problem with indentation, could you explain?

Comment: Its a matter of taste, but I think when you are indenting four levels for basically a set of dependant answers, that it doesnt add much to the clarity of the code, and I find the above clearer (though its looking like I am on my own).

Comment: @aronp: where do you see 4 levels of indentation in this answer? There is only one level.

Comment: If it were written as "if (condition1) { if (condition2) { if coundition3 {dosomething()}}}" you end up with three levels of indentation, 4 was indicative!

Comment: aronp, you clearly don't think like the rest of us if you think what you wrote is at all clear.

Comment: @Dov, I think the answers to this have made that abundantly clear, I count one comment saying in certain circumstances it might be okay vs. the rest.  I hadnt expected it to be so clear cut as a no-no so I have learnt something (which I guess is the point of SO). (though I confess for my own private code I'll probably keep using it though probably with the do {} while(false) version

Answer (score 7):

You may have heard of these things modern programming languages have, called *functions* ;)
One of the key reasons `goto` is no longer used is that we can now factor code out into separate functions, and call them instead.

One way to solve your problem would be to put the code in a separate function instead, and *return* instead of breaking from your pseudo-loop:

```
void safedosomething() {
    if (!condition1)
        return;

    condition2.setup();

    if (!condition2)
        return;

    condition3.setup();

    if (!condition3)
        return;

    dosomething();
}
```

or write helper functions (such as `bool checkcondition1() { condition1.setup(); return condition1; }`) which set up and then test the conditions, and use a boolean flag:

```
bool valid = true;

if (!checkcondition1())
    valid = false;

if (!checkcondition2())
    valid = false;

if (!checkcondition3())
    valid = false;

if (!checkcondition4())
    valid = false;

if (valid) dosomething();
```

or a bit more concisely:

```
bool valid = true;

valid &&= checkcondition1();
valid &&= checkcondition2();
valid &&= checkcondition3();
valid &&= checkcondition4();

if (valid) dosomething();
```

or just

```
if (checkcondition1()
  && checkcondition2()
  && checkcondition3()
  && checkcondition4())
    dosomething();
```

There are plenty of ways to express this, without counterintuitive loops-that-don't-loop.

Comment: I think your first answer deals with the more complicated situations best, but dont you think that you are using multiple return points to effectively implement goto's.  Is that really that much better, plus the function might actually have a big fat interface as well, just to check three conditions.  Made me think!

Comment: @aronp: yes, I use multiple return points, but I don't see a problem with that. It *may* be an issue in C, because you have no automatic way to perform cleanup when returning, but in C++, with RAII, there is no problem with multiple returns. And yes, from a code clarity point of view, it is a lot better. If the function has a very complicated interface one option (apart from simplifying it, perhaps by refactoring the individual conditions), could be to write the function as a C++0x lambda, so it can capture local variables implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this construct is because `goto` is a dirty word in programming. But lets face it, you are effectively using the loop construct to do the same thing. My opinion on this is either be honest and use the `goto` or refactor the code.

Comment: I think it is slightly more structured than goto, but get the point.

Comment: @aronp I think it's precisely a `goto` , BUT it's less readable because it doesn't actually use the `goto` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

C++ only, unfortunately:

```
if ( condition1
     && (condition2.setup(), condition2)
     && (condition3.setup(), condition3) )
{
    dosomething();
}
```

For something java compatible (but I'm still writing C++!) I would fall back to something along the lines of this. (Obviously, some context may need to be passed into `CheckConditions()`.)

```
bool CheckConditions()
{
    if (!condition1)
        return false;

    condition2.setup();

    if (!condition2)
        return false;

    condition3.setup();

    if (!condition3)
        return false;

    return true;
}

//...
if (CheckConditions())
{
    dosomething();
}
//...
```

Comment: Interesting use of brackets!  Again not sure I like relying on order of evaluation in expressions (across languages etc) but clever.

Comment: @aronp: The order of evaluation is guaranteed. Both `,` and `&&` imply sequence points.

Comment: I realise that, but that is for c++.  I dont know about across all languages where this construct could be used, and I dont know that everyone else knows that.  I just prefer not to rely on it.

Comment: @aronp: I did say "C++ only" and it was one of the two languages that you asked about. The question is academic for the other language as java does not have a comma operator. Both languages guarantee short-circuiting for `&&`. I have updated with a solution that is applicable to java as well.

Comment: now we're talking... this answer actually duplicates the code specified, unlike the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem concerned that evaluating condition 2 requires some setup, and you don't know where to put it.  Refactor that into a separate boolean method and then use that the way almost everybody here has described.  For example:

```
if (checkCondition1() && checkCondition2(someInput) && checkCondition3()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

and..

```
private boolean checkCondition2(Object someInput) {
    //setup condition 2
    return condition2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && ...)
```

was simply that it could become hard to read and edit if there are lots of conditions, although you could always write it like this:

```
if ( condition1 &&
     condition2 &&
     condition3 ... )
    doStuff();
```

How about you turn the loop into a function:

```
bool all()
{
    if (!condition1) return false;
    if (!condition2) return false;
    if (!condition3) return false;      
    ....
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Affraid I dont like the function idea, it would be bool all(param1, param2, param3, param4 ...), give you the overhead of a function call and essentially achieve the same result.

Comment: out of interest, what do your conditions look like? If they are in a convenient format to be passed as parameters, how about a for:each loop? valid = true; for (condition in conditions) { if (!condition) {valid = false; break;}} if (valid) doStuff();

Comment: @aronp: "overhead of a function call"? Not really. The compiler can inline the call *if it is a problem*, but most likely it isn't. And it doesn't achieve "essentially the same result". It gives you readable and reusable code. The `all()` function can be called again the next time you need to check the same conditions. The original pseudo-loop would have to be copy-pasted. But most importantly, it results in code that the reader can make sense of.

Comment: Affraid this code doesnt format very well. boolean check = false;

// this loop never loops
for (;;)
{
 boolean connected = (WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(ss) == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED
   || WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(ss) == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR);

 if (!connected)
 {
  break;
 }

 locNet = mFoundNetworks.get(key);

 if (locNet == null )
 {
  LOG.w(TAG, "Got unkown network connection");
  break;
 }

 if (locNet.nd.Open == 0)
 {
  LOG.v(TAG, "Not Open");
  break;
 }

 check = true;
 break;
}

if (check)
 {
  dosomething();
 }

Comment: @aronp: oh dear.. no, forget the for:each loop. It would have been cool if it was basically the same value being compared to different other values. If you're worried about function call overhead, you might want to cache the return value of WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(ss) instead of calling it twice.

Comment: Good point (missed that). I'm not really that concerned about the processing overhead of functions, just the hassle overhead of writing them when I thought the construct was fairly clear, -1 on reputation and not a voice of support (though I did like the "if i was checking the same value it might be okay", I get that) makes me think its not a habit that is going to win friends or influence people!

Comment: The "conditions" have side effects... it looks more and more as a good candidate to extract into a helper function. The number of actual code lines is not negligible and the flow is not trivial, keeping it in the same function with the weird construct will make it even harder to read, and to interpret what the overall function is doing... On the other hand, a function with a couple of fall through returns is something most people is familiar with, and if the function name is appropriate you will not even have to dwell into the gory details of the conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Here's sort of compromise, if you want to keep the indentation as it is:

```
boolean valid = true;  // optimistic start

if (!valid || !condition1)
   valid = false;

if (!valid || !condition2)
   valid = false;

if (!valid || !condition3)
   valid = false;

if (valid)
   doSomething();
```

The `!valid` in the first `if` statement is superflucious but doesn't harm, could be kept for readability. `else/if` is more elegant, to my opinion, but that's just an opinion.

But I really wouldn't (ab-)use the for loop and I never ever would find a cheap way to implement a pseudo-goto. There's always a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Adreas, I am affraid I dont really like it because it depends on the order of evaluation of conditions in if statements (condition2 could be checked even though condition1 has failed IF the order of evaluation was different, I know it isnt but dont like relying on that)

Comment: @aronp If you're planning to port this to a variety of languages then you may have a valid concern. In C++ (and C) relying on the order of evaluation can actually make your code clearer since it's been that way for decades.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a loop if there is a break statement at the end of the loop. Arent you just iterating once, no matter the situation?

Anyway, you'll usually find two differing opinions concerning this on SO, one being that break statements shouldn't be used at all, and one being that it depends on the situation.

I tend to fall in with the latter group, but the way that your loop works uses superfluous break statements. I'd much rather structure such a loop like this:

```
bool valid = true;

for(... ; .... && valid == true ; ....)
{
     if (!condition1)
        valid = false;

     if (!condition2)
        valid = false;

     if (!condition3)
        valid = false;

}
```

This allows a loop exit that I think is more elegant.

Comment: the first paragraph here shows exactly *why* the OPs code is bad. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having such a long if statement is most likely bad coding. 
It makes it very hard to test, and is most likely a code smell.
If possible you should refactor to take advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

How about relocating the setup to the operator bool on the Condition class?  This makes it far more readable and hides the mechanics.

```
class Condition
{
    bool _isSet;
public:
    Condition() : _isSet(false) {
    }
    void setup() {
        _isSet = true;
    }
    operator bool () {
        if (!_isSet) {
            setup();
        }
        return rand() & 1;
    }
};

void doSomething()
{
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Condition cond1, cond2, cond3;
    if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) {
        doSomething();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take that code out to a separate function and use multiple return statements. You will likely need to refactor the long list of `if` statements into a separate function anyway.

```
bool isValid()
{
    if (!condition1)
        return false;

    condition2.setup();

    if (!condition2)
        return false;

    condition3.setup();

    if (!condition3)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then you could use it in your code:

```
if (isValid()) dosomething();
```